# apache2.4 + php-fpm + phpmyadmin in debian

Tags: phpmyadmin, debian, php, apache2.4

I have this setup in a debian: apache 2.4 proxy_fcgi and php-fpm (v5.5). In my virtualhost file i have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock|fcgi://./var/www/html
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

and everything works fine, i can see phpinfo() and every php file i request under /var/www/html/.

I continue with the phpmyadmin installation from the debian repo but when i browse to http://MY.IP/phpmyadmin i get a "File not found" error and in the apache error log

```
"[proxy_fcgi:error] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'"
```

Debian phpmyadmin package dumps the contents into /usr/share/phpmyadmin. If i create a test.html file under /usr/share/phpmyadmin i can see its contents from http://MY.IP/phpmyadmin/test.html

The problem is that php files under /usr/share/phpmyadmin are not being processed. The phpmyadmin apache configuration is this:

```
# phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration

Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php

        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
                <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
                    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
                </FilesMatch>

                php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
                php_flag track_vars On
                php_flag register_globals Off
                php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
                php_value include_path .
                php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
                php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/
        </IfModule>

</Directory>
...
```

and is loaded in apache configuration file.

Since there is no mod_php installed there is no processing for the php files. How can i tell apache to use proxy_fcgi to process php files under /usr/share/phpmyadmin directory ?

**>>update<<**
I added a proxypassmatch directive in phpmyadmin apache's conf

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/phpmyadmin/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock|fcgi:///usr/share/phpmyadmin/
```

expecting to work but i keep getting the same error.

**>>update 2<<**
I replaced the php-fpm unix socket with network (127.1:9000) and replaced the virthualhost file's ProxyPassmatch with:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/$1
```

and in phpmyadmin's apache conf:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/phpmyadmin/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/usr/share/phpmyadmin/$1
ProxyPassMatch ^/phpmyadmin/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/usr/share/phpmyadmin$1index.php
```

and everything works.. when i go to MY.IP/phpinfo.php i get the phpinfo from /var/www/html/phpinfo.php and when i visit MY.IP/phpmyadmin/phpinfo.php i get the processed contents of /usr/share/phpmyadmin/phpinfo.php.

My problem is solved but i still don't understand why the network connection with php-fpm works but the unix socket doesn't.

Comment: If I could kiss you I would, pure genious!

Comment: You saved my life! thanks a lot !

Comment: I have also tried working it with Unix sockets until I gave up. It won't work. So decided to fall back to tcp connection!!

Comment: If anybody is still around, please [I need your help](https://serverfault.com/questions/1109703/phpmyadmin-install-on-debian-10-fails-proxy-fcgierror-error-parsing-url) on phpmyadmin, Debian 10 and FPM/FastCGI. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I was struggling with this exact same issue and I could not get phpmyadmin to work. I was still getting the "File not found" mentioned above. My issue was I had to put mine in my ProxyPassMatch inside of my 000-default.conf file inside of my ./sites-available folder and I had to put these entries BEFORE my default one. This was outline at the very bottom of this page where I found the solution:
http://jordanconway.com/set-up-apache-2-4-with-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-13-10/

Here is the way I have mine setup for reference.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ...
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
   ...
    ProxyPassMatch ^/phpmyadmin/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/usr/share/phpmyadmin/$1
    ProxyPassMatch ^/phpmyadmin/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/usr/share/phpmyadmin$1index.php
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

Could this be due to a fact that sockets are being [supported from Apache 2.4.9](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM#Performance_and_Pitfalls) and you used some earlier build of 2.4 perhaps?

Comment: yup, that was the problem with unix socket, Apache supports unix socket from v2.4.9 and above (or with a patch for v2.4.7). I was using 2.4.7 but at that time Apache documentation didn't specify that the unix socket was not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you solved this.

1. Your PHPMyAdmin was set to use mod_php5, which likely wasn't installed since you are using PHP via PHP-FPM.
2. You correctly identified that phpmyadmin setup required a proxypass which had the correct path to the PHP files.

For the last bit, usually php-fpm will listen on a unix socket **or** on TCP but not both. What's the `listen` directive set to in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`? Are there more than one `listen` directives defined?

I'm guessing there is just the one `Listen 127.0.0.1:9000` set in there.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add HTTP2 to apache HTTPD and it stopped phpmyadmin from working because of having to remove mod_php.

Open /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

Comment out

```
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
```

Add in <Directory

```
<FilesMatch \.php> # Apache 2.4.10+ can proxy to unix socket
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>
```